# Show local images from file server in browser

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have an old ASPX app that displays images from our file server in a browser, it works in IE8 on XP, but our XP machines are starting to die.

The images do not display in IE10 or chrome.  I don't really care which browser we use.  here is a screenshot[image]

Comment: If you copy the url from the source and post it in your browser, does it display the image? if not-> wrong file path

Comment: Chrome is reporting "not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: Here is the URL:  file://///dp-2/Root_Images/622625/Danielle Buisness cards-001-1.jpg  In IE, if I put this in the address bar, it auto redirects to:  \\dp-2\Root_Images\622625\Danielle Buisness cards-001-1.jpg and loads the image correctly